# Entering line breaks in NSString

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I need to set mail Body in MFMailComposeViewController to separate some text in number of lines. I am using the following line of code but it isn't working.

```
[mail setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi I am Interested to buy a vehicle for me Name :%@ %@ \n Contact No. : %@ \n Email : %@\n",txtFirst.text, txtLast.text, txtContact.text, txtEmail.text ] isHTML:YES];
```

also i tried this

```
[mail setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi I am Interested to buy a vehicle for me Name :%@ %@ </br> Contact No. : %@ </br> Email : %@</br>",txtFirst.text, txtLast.text, txtContact.text, txtEmail.text ] isHTML:YES];
```

is there any solution to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
[mail setMessageBody:
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First:%@
                           \r\n Second:%@
                           \r\n Third:%@
                           \r\n Fourth:%@",
txtFirst.text, txtSecond.text, txtThird.text, txtFourth.text ] isHTML:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have `isHTML` set to YES in your message, use `<br/>` to do a line break, if `isHTML` is NO, use `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Your messageBody is set to HTML what will mean that you need to add `</ br>` for line break, or set `isHTML:NO`